# Why is my Bootstrap navigation bar not displaying properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Note: I just want to mention that I am new at HTML, CSS and using Bootstrap, so it could be that I messed up something by mistake, but I just don't know what.

I'm currently working on a website and I've been struggling at trying to fix my navigation bar. [This is the problem I'm having with the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reHHs.png). What is causing the shopping cart and login icons to be displayed below the menu rather than at the end of the navigation bar?

Below is the CSS and html for that section. I know Bootstrap comes with some settings, and I've tried using inspect element to figure it out but I can't isolate what is messing up my code.

HTML:

```
div class="nav">
    <!-- menu bars -->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active col-sm-auto" id="menu-item"><a href="../P1/index.html">Home</a></li><br/>
          <li class="active col-sm-auto" id="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn" id="aisle">Aisle</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="../P2-P3/john/fruits.html">Fruits</a>
              <a href="../P2-P3/joon/vegetables/vegetables.html"
                >Vegetables</a
              >
              <a href="../P2-P3/joon/meats/meats.html">Meats</a>
              <a href="../P2-P3/joon/milk_eggs/milk_eggs.html"
                >Milk & Eggs</a
              >
              <a href="../P2-P3/ulas/snacks-aisle.html">Snacks</a>
              <a href="../P2-P3/francis/beverages.html">Beverages</a>
              <a href="../P2-P3/eve/prepared-meals.html">Prepared meals</a>
            </div>
          </li><br/>
          <li class="active col-sm-auto" id="menu-item"><a href="#">Deals</a></li><br/>
          <li class="active col-sm-auto" id="menu-item"><a href="#">Services</a></li><br/>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <div class="shopping-cart">
            <a href="../P4/P4-shopping_cart.html" class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="shopping-cart"></a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="user-login">
              <a href="../P5/P5-login.html" class="fas fa-user">Sign up</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* navigation bar styling */
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: #a0b284;
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
.navbar {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: MontserratLight;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f6f8f2;
    overflow:-moz-hidden-unscrollable;
    padding-left: 1%;
}
#menu-item {
    width: 115px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#menu-item a:link{
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
#menu-item a:hover {
    color: #c8d1bb;
}
.navbar-right {
   float: right;
   display: inline-block;
}

#shopping-cart {
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
#shopping-cart:hover {
    color: #c8d1bb;
}
#shopping-cart:visited {
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
.user-login {
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
.user-login:visited {
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
.navbar a:visited {
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    color: #c8d1bb;
}
#shopping-cart {
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
}
.dropbtn {
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #a0b284;
    color: #f6f8f2;
    padding-right: 70px;
    border: none;
    border-right: 2px;
    border-right-color: #f6f8f2;
    border-right-width: 2px;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f6f8f2;
    color: #a0b284;
    min-width: none;
    max-width: 110px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px 0px #777777;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a:link {
    color: #b3c39c;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:visited {
    color: #b3c39c;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #b3c39c;
    color: #f6f8f2;
}
#dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #b3c39c;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have two seperate navbars. One for your main links, and a seperate one for login and the shopping cart. You should just move your shopping cart and login link into your main navbar, and put a style of "float: right;" on them. That should alleviate your problem.